# How to solve this ODE (Maybe Riccati type?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

How would I solve this ODE. I am solving a PDE and have managed to reduce it to this, but can't solve it:

$$
\frac{dh_1(t)}{dt} + \mu -\frac{h_1(t)}{\frac{k}{\alpha} +(T-t)}=0
$$

Where $h_1(T)=-\alpha $ and $C,\mu,k,\alpha$ are constants.

If there was no constant $\mu$, it would be simple to solve. I have attempted to reduce it further using:

$$
h_1(t)=-\mu t +h_2(t)
$$

to eliminate the $\mu$, and this gave the following equation which I still don't know how to solve:

$$
\frac{dh_2(t)}{dt}  +\frac{\mu t-h_2(t)}{\frac{k}{\alpha} +(T-t)}=0
$$

Comment: Are these equal to 0? You can't solve a diff Eq without an equality sign! put them in :)

Answer (score 1):

I will tackle the second equation,

You can use that to resolve your first:

We are solving

$$ \frac{dh_2(t)}{dt} + \frac{\mu t - h_2(t)}{\frac{k}{a} + T - t} = 0$$

We swap around terms to get the form

$$ \frac{dh_2(t)}{dt}  - \frac{1}{\frac{k}{a} + T - t} h_2(t) = -\frac{\mu t }{\frac{k}{a} + T - t}$$

Now consider this general abstract form:

$$ \frac{dh_2(t)}{dt}  - \Omega_1(t) h_2(t) = \Omega_2(t)$$

Multiply both sides by $e^{- \int \Omega_1(t) dt}$, to yield

$$e^{- \int \Omega_1(t) dt}\frac{dh_2(t)}{dt}  + e^{- \int \Omega_1(t) dt}\Omega_1(t) h_2(t) = e^{- \int \Omega_1(t) dt}\Omega_2(t) $$

The left hand side though is just

$$ \left(e^{- \int \Omega_1(t) dt}h_2(t) \right)'$$

(verify this with the product rule!)

So we have that

$$ \left(e^{-\int \Omega_1(t) dt}h_2(t) \right)' = \frac{\Omega_2(t)}{e^{ \int \Omega_1(t) dt}}$$

Meaning that

$$ e^{- \int \Omega_1(t) dt}h_2(t) = \int \frac{\Omega_2(t)}{e^{ \int \Omega_1(t) dt}} dt $$

And so

$$ h_2(t) = e^{ \int \Omega_1(t) dt} \int \frac{\Omega_2(t)}{e^{ \int \Omega_1(t) dt}} dt $$

SO now plug in $\Omega_1(t) =  \frac{1}{\frac{k}{a} + T - t}$ and $\Omega_2(t) = -\frac{\mu t }{\frac{k}{a} + T - t}$ and get ready to do a LOT of algebra!

$$\int \Omega_1(t) dt = -\ln \left( \frac{k}{a} + T - t\right), e^{\int \Omega_1(t) dt} = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{k}{a} + T - t\right)}$$

So

$$ h_2(t) = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{k}{a} + T - t\right)} \int - \mu t dt  = - \frac{ \frac{\mu}{2} t^2 + C}{\frac{k}{a} + T - t}$$

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks so much! The trick was the integrating factor, which I couldn't see!

Comment: There's a mistake!

Comment: Let me correct it :)

Comment: All set!, Go over it, let me know if anything doesn't make sense